# iptable connetion to VPN Server (VPN + DNS)

Tags: iptables, vpn

i want to create iptable rules that allow no traffic to the outside world with the exception to my VPN - Server (xx.xx.xx.xx) and local Network 192.168.0.0/24

The rules i defined:

```
iptables -F 
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

First i had problem with the DNS for IP resolving but now im getting from my openvpn client: **Temporary failure in name resolution**

Without the Rules there is no problem and everything works great.

**UPDATE**
To answer the question from the comment:
It's a VPN Gateway for an internal network.
If the VPN Server istn reachable no traffic should go on eth0

Comment: Your question is lacking some key-points (eg.: is this a "single" box? Or is a VPN-gateway for an "internal" network? Which VPN technologies are you using?). Anyway, as a first line of troubleshooting, ensure IP connectivity towards remote VPN server (your traffic CANNOT flow inside the VPN-tunnel _IF_ the VPN-server is unreachable!); 2) to ensure that all the outbound traffic is routed inside the VPN-tunnel, it's as easy as add a proper default route. The only (critical) exception is the traffic towards VPN server, that need to flow OUTSIDE the VPN. So you need a preliminary static-route.